# Matrix computation using JS array and Math object - Hyperledger Composer Transaction Processor Function

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-composer

I would like to perform 2D matrix computation (multiplication, divide, sqrt) in transaction processor funnction (TP) in composer smart contract. I know, currently I **cannot use external npm module such as mathjs** in TP function.

Therefore, I am thinking of creating array within array and then using **javascript Math object and loops** for computation. Would it possible to use this **Math** object in TP? 
Is it possible that this may produce **non-deterministic** results?
Can anyone suggest me any other approach?

Best Regards,

Akshay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it should be possible. The Math object is a built-in object so you should be able to use a static method like `Math.round(4.7)` etc in a TP function  etc etc when executed by the prevailing javascript interpreter in the runtime container hosting the smart contract / business network.